# Next block inside of a loop

Tags: matrix, forloop, loop, previous-next

I’m struggling with getting the next `block` inside of a loop of a Matrix-Field. I’ve tried this:

```
{% set nextBlock = entry.articleContent.offset(1).limit(1) %}
{% if nextBlock.type == "textBox" %}
 {{ nextBlock.textTitle }}
{% endif %}
```

This produces an **ArgumentCountError**. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Your `nextBlock` is currently an object of type `ElementCriteriaModel` so you have a query but you don't use it. In order to execute the search you need to use the `first()` function. Or you could use the `block.getNext()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
{% set nextBlock = block.getNext() %}
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel#getNext